# Unable to resolve dependency when docker-compose build

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose, dockerfile

Here are my files. From the dependency error section below, think the issue is due to not being able to resolve a dependency tree and resolving a dependency.

## docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  django:
    build: ./api
    command: ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app/api
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    command: ["npm", "start"]
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app/frontend
      - node-modules:/app/frontend/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

volumes:
  node-modules:
```

## Dockerfile for Django (api)

```
FROM python:3.4

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        postgresql-client \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app/api
COPY requirements.txt /app/api
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

## Dockerfile for front end

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /app/frontend
COPY package.json /app/frontend

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

## Dependency Error

```
docker-compose up
[+] Building 50.4s (13/17)
 => [django-react-csv-conorjohanlon_frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile              0.1s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 31B                                                                       0.0s 
 => [django-react-csv-conorjohanlon_django internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                0.1s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                       0.0s 
 => [django-react-csv-conorjohanlon_django internal] load .dockerignore                                   0.1s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                           0.0s 
 => [django-react-csv-conorjohanlon_frontend internal] load .dockerignore                                 0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                           0.0s 
 => [django-react-csv-conorjohanlon_django internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.4      17.7s 
 => [django-react-csv-conorjohanlon_frontend internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:latest   16.8s 
 => [django-react-csv-conorjohanlon_frontend 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/node@sha256:88becea956ea5ec0262  0.0s 
 => [django-react-csv-conorjohanlon_frontend internal] load build context                                 0.1s 
 => => transferring context: 648B                                                                         0.0s 
 => CACHED [django-react-csv-conorjohanlon_frontend 2/4] WORKDIR /app/frontend                            0.0s 
 => CACHED [django-react-csv-conorjohanlon_frontend 3/4] COPY package.json /app/frontend                  0.0s 
 => ERROR [django-react-csv-conorjohanlon_frontend 4/4] RUN npm install                                  32.6s 
 => CANCELED [django-react-csv-conorjohanlon_django 1/5] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.4@sha256:7a7e4  32.0s 
 => => resolve docker.io/library/python:3.4@sha256:7a7e47efdfd6503afcf56a57f981bcc23d54211ad3b3c21cbe4bd  0.0s 
 => => sha256:8c62b065252f2bc1c6a859acd18df1bb2aba260c47a593d6a7de9b34239727e5 7.40kB / 7.40kB            0.0s 
 => => sha256:7a7e47efdfd6503afcf56a57f981bcc23d54211ad3b3c21cbe4bd597873fa6e1 2.37kB / 2.37kB            0.0s 
 => => sha256:c7862254606d2e762075c2e51cdc615fda1023f8604f0b91d9893c1cca298b11 2.22kB / 2.22kB            0.0s 
 => => sha256:6fba9447437b5ee1da9b33b2e2d18add55a33d0b763075202e17cad7efd3ff8f 4.34MB / 4.34MB            6.7s 
 => => sha256:0250231711a047a6e54e7107d7a3bfb0afd807f5f408d00be0d407c5b8395219 10.78MB / 10.78MB         14.7s 
 => => sha256:22dbe790f71562dfd3d49406b1dfd1e85e50f3dd7cb2e97b3918376ca39cae4e 21.73MB / 45.34MB         32.1s 
 => => sha256:c2b4d327b352258a8208acc249d97d70cac3c5cda0cea4a08de4de3cb406d8e5 17.83MB / 50.07MB         32.1s 
 => => sha256:270e1baa52991965b3f6894a941b703500d5cc07550f9fcbd9b2fc0d86103389 10.49MB / 215.05MB        32.1s 
 => => transferring context: 128B                                                                         0.0s 
------
 > [django-react-csv-conorjohanlon_frontend 4/4] RUN npm install:
#11 32.12 npm notice
#11 32.12 npm notice New minor version of npm available! 8.3.1 -> 8.4.1
#11 32.13 npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.4.1>
#11 32.13 npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@8.4.1` to update!
#11 32.13 npm notice
#11 32.18 npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
#11 32.27 npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
#11 32.27 npm ERR!
#11 32.27 npm ERR! While resolving: cra@0.1.0
#11 32.27 npm ERR! Found: react@15.7.0
#11 32.27 npm ERR! node_modules/react
#11 32.27 npm ERR!   react@"^15.7.0" from the root project
#11 32.27 npm ERR!
#11 32.27 npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
#11 32.27 npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0.0" from reactstrap@6.5.0
#11 32.28 npm ERR! node_modules/reactstrap
#11 32.28 npm ERR!   reactstrap@"^6.5.0" from the root project
#11 32.28 npm ERR!
#11 32.29 npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
#11 32.29 npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
#11 32.29 npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
#11 32.29 npm ERR!
#11 32.29 npm ERR! See /root/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
#11 32.33
#11 32.33 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#11 32.33 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-02-07T20_45_33_365Z-debug-0.log
------
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm install]: exit code:
```

The error message above says to run `npm install -g npm@8.4.1` to update but i still get the error.

Any help is appreciated

## EDIT ----------

Turns out my dependencies needed React 16 and 17  which was causing the issue. Within my packagae.json file in my frontend folder, I changed the version of dependencies 'react' and 'react-dom' from 17.0.0 to 16.13.0.

AAAND IT WORKS!

Comment: The error you quote doesn't seem to have anything to do with Docker; it says your dependencies simultaneously need React versions 15 and 16.  If you remove this entire Docker setup and run `npm install` on the host without Docker, do you get the same error?  (Is that an easier environment to debug and fix it?)

Comment: thanks, the packagae.json in my frontend folder includes the dependencies that are causing this error!  I am able to run npm install in my 'frontend folder' which had 106 vulnerabilities (19 low, 66 moderate, 21 high). I ran npm audit fix --force which wasn't able to resolve the dependency (see my post)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @DavidMaze I've updated my original post with the outcome of the npm install and audit force

Comment: edit --so the problem is fixed. All i had to do was change the version of the troublesom dependecies in my package.json file! Whats crazy is i self diagnosed the issue and I was changing the dependcies a couple of hours ago which did not work.. Turns out I was changing the wrong dependecies! Thanks

Comment: You don't want to mount your local `node_modules` folder. It's more common to use a blind mount to ensure the container only uses `node_modules` from the `npm install`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68855603/283366)

Comment: Better not use any volumes at all for this kind of thing. Either develop locally or build the image and run it without mounting the code. Sometimes it may make sense but I think in case of nodejs that's very rare of the case. NPM packages usually don't have any system dependencies that you would need to install, and they all live nicely in the node_modules folder. So there is no benefit in exchange for the additional overhead. If you use venv, python is mostly fine on the host too. Sometimes you need certain database drivers and so where it could make sense to go for mounted code.

Comment: I changed `COPY package.json /app/frontend` to `COPY package*.json /app/frontend` and it worked