# Dockerize React App doest not update when I change the code

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I am having trouble with docker while working with React app.
I have a three-layer application. Python, Postgress DB and React.
I showing my Dockerfile and Docker-compose file. Can you please help me what is wrong?

When I change the code in my app it does not appear in docker, only when I delete the image and build it again.

When I add this line of code to Home.jsx (homepage of app)
*<>Trying hot update</>* -> It should show this text in the browser right the way or after refresh, but it does not.

DOCKERFILE

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /ipharm-fe
ENV PATH /ipharm-fe/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@5.0.0 -g --silent

COPY . ./

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  ipharm-app:
    container_name: ipharm_app
    image: conceptica/ipharm_app:local
    depends_on:
      - ipharm-postgres
    env_file: &envs-ipharm-app
      - .envs/.development/.ipharm_app
      - .envs/.development/.ipharm_postgres
      - .envs/.development/.ipharm_redis
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: scripts/start.sh
    volumes:
       - .:/usr/src/app

  ipharm-postgres:
    container_name: ipharm_postgres
    image: postgres:13.4-alpine
    env_file:
      - .envs/.development/.ipharm_postgres
    volumes:
      - ./_postgres_data_ipharm:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  ipharm-frontend:
    container_name: ipharm_frontend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - .envs/.development/.ipharm_frontend
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - '.:/ipharm_fe'  
      - '/ipharm_fe/node_modules'
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

It has been working before. Just when I reinstall my system, clone git, and build docker again it stopped working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing dependencies after using docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68855526/missing-dependencies-after-using-docker-compose). You also need to volume mount `.:/ipharm-fe` instead of `/usr/src/app`

Comment: Hello Phil, thank you for your unswer. Sorry but I do not see how link you have send can help me. 
About volume I am mounting .:/ipharm_fe (see the last service in docker-compose)
When I change it to .:/ipharm-fe I get 
ERROR in EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/ipharm-fe/node_modules/.cache'

Comment: Ah, sorry. I thought `ipharm-app` was your frontend. How does it _not work_

Comment: When I change to .:/ipharm-fe  and ipharm-fe/nodemodules
I get ERROR in EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/ipharm-fe/node_modules/.cache'